# configure error : size of "void*" is less than "long"

Tags: apache, arm, cross-compiling, powerpc

> configure error : size of "void*" is less than "long"

This is the error I'm getting when i'm cross compiling apache for powerpc

Comment: can anyone please help me in solving this..i'm stuck on this since morning.

Comment: same problem but I my cross build is for arm

Answer (score 1):

I added "ap_cv_void_ptr_lt_long=4" to my build config options. Then the configure script run through.

Look for the following lines when running ./configure to find the right size:

```
checking for inline... inline
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether setpgrp takes no argument... (cached) no
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking size of void*... 4
checking size of char... 1
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 4
checking size of short... 2
checking size of long long... 8
checking for INT64_C... yes
checking size of pid_t... 8
checking whether ssize_t and int are the same... yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have /usr/local/lib in /etc/ld.so.conf file.

Try again after doing this-

```
echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf

ldconfig
```

Answer (score -1):

You compiled apache for powerpc 64?

Maybe you have to check the configuration before compiled, to set the proper configuration options.